# How to create migrations for a file containing a single class

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.9

I have this project structure :-

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRCkr.png)

As you can see, I have a directory 'common' in which there resides a file named user_model.py which contains a model class. That directory is just below my mange.py directory(project root).

Now to want to create migrations for that model.
Please provide baby steps to do that.

Appreciate for your answers.